# Returning from Asynch Task to MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I read a lot about it and tried many things, without having succes. But it doesn't seem hard at all, so I guess I am missing a little thing.

I got 2 classes, a `MainActivity` and an `asynch task` class.
the `doInBackground`task is working perfectly.
But when it is done, I want to program to continue at a certain point in my `MainActivity`

```
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        Log.d("control", "ZipHelper.unzip() - File: " + _archive);
        ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile(_archive);
        for (Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> e = zipfile.entries(); e
                .hasMoreElements();) {
            ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
            unzipEntry(zipfile, entry, _outputDir);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("control", "ZipHelper.unzip() - Error extracting file "
                + _archive + ": " + e);
        setZipError(true);
    }
    return null;
}
protected void onPostExecute(Integer... result) {
    //Here something like MainActivity.showPicture();
}
```

I know I must do something with `onPostExecute`, but I don't know what exactly.
So let's say, I want to show a Toast in my `MainActivity` after `asynch-task` is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Listener interface.

**Example :**

Listener Interface

```
public interface AsyncTaskListener
{
    public void onTaskComplete();
}
```

**ZipHelper Class**

```
public class ZipHelper extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>
{
    private String filename;
    private AsyncTaskListener listener;
    private File file;
    public ZipHelper(String filename, File file, AsyncTaskListener listener)
    {
        this.filename = filename;
        this.file = file;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        //stuff here
    }

    @override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        //Background stuff here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer... result)
    {
        listener.onTaskComplete();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity implements AsyncTaskListener
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        //Your stuff

        new ZipHelper(zip[0].mZipFileName, file, MainActivity.this).execute();
    }

    public void onTaskComplete()
    {
        //AsyncTask post stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: So I am making a separated class for the `interface`?

Comment: For simply showing a `Toast`, just passing `Activity context` is the best and easiest way, IMHO

Comment: OP said that must do something but really dont know what it is. Toast is an example. OP clearly stated in previous statement that **when it is done, I want to program to continue at a certain point in my MainActivity**. For this I think Listener Interface is best option.

Comment: Could help me a little bit more? I still can't figure it out. This was my original execute: `new ZipHelper(zip[0].mZipFileName, file).execute();` and my `asynch task` is called `ZipHelper`. So I also need to send 2 more variables.

Comment: It is working, code was getting a mess after trying so many things. But thanks! Would never thought this myself.

Answer (score 0):

Without calling a certain method in your `MainActivity` you can't feasibly start at a certain point in your `MainActivity`. The point of `AsyncTask` is to allow your calling `Activity` to keep going and not hold up the `UI`. What you can do is pass a `context` to your `AsyncTask` and show the `Toast` in `onPostExecute()`

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void ,Void> {  // use whatever params you need here
private Context context;

public MyTask(Context c) {
    context = c;
} 

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
     super.onPostExecute(result);
     Toast.makeText(context, "You did it!". Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

and call it by passing your `Context`

```
Mytask task = new MyTask(this);  //or MyActivity.this depending on where you are
task.execute();  // pass params if you need
```

I suggest using `Activity context` instead of `Application context` for `Toast`