# General AsyncTask, use one AsyncTask in multiple contexts

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm using AsyncTask and all the examples I found about an AsyncTask is inside an activity.

I'm trying to make an application with a lot of activity and some must download a HTML page. I don't really want to copy-paste the same code all the time in every activity. I find this to be dirty.

So I need to do it as a special class Async HttpGet and pass the function with an argument. I will execute after the doinbackground (different for every activity).

Is this possible or do I need to copy-paste my code in every activity and change the do in background to do what I need after downloading the HTML page?

Comment: I've just answered a [similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477091/use-the-same-asynctask-to-update-different-views/16477195#16477195) and I guess this question was asked many times before.

Comment: @Jebik, You can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768449/android-can-i-put-asynctask-in-a-separate-class-and-have-a-callback

Comment: I read and this and apparently this work by the sa,e way for my probleme i will try thank

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16400981/1329126)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well what you can do is create an listener for AsyncTask completion, which listens when your AsyncTask is completed and return you the data. I had created an example to execute database queries in background thread and then returning the data to the Activity. Just [`check it`](https://github.com/lalit3686/SqliteLoaderDemo/blob/master/src/com/example/dbdemo/SqliteTask.java) and you can create similar AsyncTask for your problem.

**UPDATE:-**

- Also you can use BroadCastReceiver as a Listener when your AsyncTask is completed and return the value.
- Interface is another option for creating a Listener for AsyncTask.
  Here is a [demo from my github](https://github.com/lalit3686/AsyncTaskReturnValue)

Answer (score 3):

Just create a class that extends `AsyncTask` that you can reuse.

```
public abstract class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private final String url;

    public MyAsyncTask(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params){
        // get data from url.
        return null;
    }

}
```

And then to call it, just create an instance of that class.

```
new MyAsyncTask("http://www.google.com"){
    public void onPostExecute(String result){
        // update your views.
    }
}.execute();
```

Comment: we can "customize" or add a method direclty in class definition? :O I will try this

Comment: when we do this, the new instance makes us implement the doInBackground method. Why? i dont want that i do it in the asynctask class

Comment: I had to change the asynctask class doinBackground to @Override
 protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that from memory. Corrected.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an AsyncTask that will download data from a url and update the calling activity.

Make sure your calling activity implements the interface `DownloadDataTask.DownloadCompleteHandler` and that it passes itself as parameter to the `DownloadDataTask` constructor.

```
public class DownloadDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    public interface DownloadCompleteHandler
    {
        public void handleDownloadComplete(String result);
    }

    private DownloadCompleteHandler handler;
    private String url;

    public DownloadDataTask(DownloadCompleteHandler handler, String url) {
        this.handler = handler;
        this.url = url;
    }


    /* AsyncTask methods */

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... empty) {
        return downloadData(url);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        handler.handleDownloadComplete(result);
    }

    /* Downloading Data */

    private String downloadData(String urlStr) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = new String();

        try {
            is = getInputStream(urlStr);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                result += inputLine;            
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            return "Malformed URL: " + ex.getMessage();
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {
            return "Connection timed out";
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return "IOException: " + ex.getMessage();
        }

        finally {
            if (is != null)
                is.close();
        }

        return result;      
    }

    private InputStream getInputStream(String urlStr) throws IOException 
    {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setReadTimeout(7000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(7000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        conn.connect();
        return conn.getInputStream();
    }   
}
```